# Copying only updated/new files from one folder to another using python

Tags: python

I have written a code in python which copies files from one folder to another and it's working fine. I need to amend it so that it can only copy the new files only because with the following code, whenever I run my script, all of my files in folder_1 get copied into folder_2 and I have to deal with millions of text files so it's not a compact code right now. Anyone here who can solve this problem?

Check the following code which is running fine but not fulfilling my requirements. I only want those files to copy from Folder_1 to to Folder_2 which are not present in Folder_2...

```
import os, shutil
import os.path, time
path = 'C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/Folder_1/'
copyto= 'C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/Folder_2/'
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()

for f in files:
        print(f) #f contains the names of files
        src = path+f #path of source
        dst = copyto+f #path of destination
        shutil.copy(src,dst) #copying from source to destination
        print("This is source" +src)
        print("This is destination " +dst)
        print(f)
```

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aqiY.png)

Comment: There is `os.path.exists` to check if file is there and `os.stat` (and `os.fstat`) to retrieve modification timestamp (for comparison if newer than another timestamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As minimal change to your code, you could place the following snippet before your `shutil.copy` call with the:

```py
try:
    if os.stat(src).st_mtime < os.stat(dst).st_mtime:
        continue
except OSError:
    pass
```

What does it do? It tries to get (content) modification file of `src` and `dst`. If former is less than latter (src is considered older), move on to the next item in the loop (`continue`), otherwise we just proceed towards performing the copy. If `OSError` (or subclass thereof, likely `FileNotFoundError`) is raised presuming `src` is still there and readable we assume that `dst` does not exist and `stat` call failed for that reason, so we ignore the exception and also moving on to the `shutil.copy` call.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me :). One more question, if I want to synchronize these tw folders so that if I update any changes in one folder updates those changes in the second folder as well.. Any suggestions? @Ondrej K.

Comment: You mean watch the directory for changes and perform copy/sync when something happens. I guess on Linux I'd look into [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), but your question seems to be pertaining to Windows and unfortunately there I cannot be of much help.

Comment: Actully my idea is to copy files from hard disk mounted on raspberry pi having raspbian and my script will run on raspberrypi. So copying frome one folder to another folder is just the starting point. 
If you can help me in this regard incase of raspbian(linux) ?
Thanks  in advance @Ondrej K

Comment: In that case, if you want to react to changes in the filesystem `inotify(7)` is a good starting point. IIRC it's not exposed in Python STL, so you'd have to either look for existing modules, bind yourself to a library, or (sort of ugly to use from Python) there is also a shell interface (`inotifywait(1)`).

Comment: Isn't it possible uisng st_mtime ? @Onderj K